# Key error: '3' When extracting data from Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

My code plan is as follows:

1) find csv files in folder using glob and create a list of files

2) covert each csv file into dataframe

3) extract data from a column location and convert into a separate dataframe

4) append the new data into a separate summary csv file

code is as follows:

```
Result = []

def result(filepath):
    files = glob.glob(filepath)
    print files
    dataframes = [pd.DataFrame.from_csv(f, index_col=None) for f in files]
    new_dfb = pd.DataFrame()

    for i, df in enumerate(dataframes):
        colname = 'Run {}'.format(i+1)
        selected_data = df['3'].ix[0:4] 
        new_dfb[colname] = selected_data
    Result.append(new_dfb)
    folder = r"C:/Users/Joey/Desktop/tcd/summary.csv"
    new_dfb.to_csv(folder)

result("C:/Users/Joey/Desktop/tcd/*.csv")

print Result
```

The code error is shown below. The issue seems to be with line 36 .. which corresponds to the  `selected_data = df['3'].ix[0:4]`.

[image]

I show one of my csv files below:

[image]

I'm not sure what the problem is with the dataframe constructor?

Comment: It seems you need to pass `header=None` to `from_csv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're csv snippet is a bit unclear. But as suggested in the comments, read_csv (from_csv in this case) automatically taken the first row as a list of headers. The behaviour you appear to want is the columns to be labelled as 1,2,3 etc. To achieve this you need to have

```
  [pd.DataFrame.from_csv(f, index_col=None,header=None) for f in files]
```